# Converting No Space date formatted as character to date

Tags: r, dataframe, date, time-series, tibble

I have a date column where each date is written without spaces and is in character format.

```
Date
<chr>
"20130402"
"20130403"
"20130404"
```

I want to convert these values to date, but it does not work.

I tried the following code to do so:

```
dataframe %>%
 as.Date(Date, origin = "2013-04-02")
```

However, this resulted in wrong dates, such as `"57128-06-03"`.
Can someone help me on how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the timezone is UTC and the format is year,month,day:

```
strptime("20130402", "%Y%m%d", tz = "UCT")
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `ymd`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
dataframe <- dataframe %>%
    mutate(Date = ymd(Date))
```